# Monitoring hardware accelerated video decoding

Tags: linux, mmal, h264

I'm using RPi4 board with Raspbian on top of it

I wonder if there is a way to tell if any process currently using hardware accelerated video playback?

Ideally it would be nice to be able to say which process exactly is using it, but it's not critical.

I know there could be various interfaces and probably it's possible to detect V4L2 M2M usage with `/dev/video10` device opened. But what's about MMAL interface? If it makes difference I'm interested in playback of H.264 videos.

I've considered following approaches but haven't found any traces:

1. Using `lsof` to track specific dev-files
2. Checking state of kernel using sys-files
3. Using `vcdbg` or `vcgencmd` to get stats

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by checking the output of

```
lsof | grep /opt/vc
```

This will list all processes which access videocore libraries. This can be further narrowed down to a specific library you're interested in. For video decoding in general, `libbcm_host` could be a good start.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but unfortunately provided solution can only indicate that application *may use* hardware accelerated video and doesn't tell if it actually uses at the moment (shared libraries linked to the app).

Comment: @reddot If you need the exact moment, run the app under `gdb` and set a breakpoint to the call you're interested in.